# Sum elements in array using x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, visual-c++, x86, floating-point, inline-assembly

I am trying to store the sum in the edx register, but the output is displayed as 0. What can be done to fix this?

```
int main() {

   float price[ ] = { 22.1, 34.44, 567.33, 2.45 };
   float sum = 0;


   __asm {

                        xor eax, eax; //counter
                        mov ebx, 4 //num elements in array
                        lea ecx, price //address of first element in array
                        xor edx, edx //store sum
                    L1 :
                        add edx, [ecx+eax*4]
                        cmp eax, ebx
                        je done

                        inc eax
                        jmp L1

                    done :
                        mov sum, edx    
   }

   cout << "sum= " << sum; 

   return 0
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `ecx` actually points to `price` after the `lea`? (Can you inspect the memory it points to?) Otherwise, even if you add floats as if they were integers, printing exactly `0` is weird (unless you are hiding essential parts). Please provide a complete [mre] (with all `#include`s, etc)!

Comment: @chtz: That LEA is correct MSVC inline asm.  It's an array so a `mov` would load the first dword.  https://godbolt.org/z/p-SVD- confirms that we get `lea     ecx, DWORD PTR _price$[ebp]`.  (But I had to fix a syntax error; missing `;` after `return 0` so this was clearly not an [mcve] that was actually tested)  I haven't found any online compiler/IDE with 32-bit MSVC where one can actually *run* the code to even try this.  I haven't tried porting to GCC or type-punning in C++ to see if maybe the exponents wrap to small enough that a `%f` style conversion produces `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building upon Peter's answer, there's still one more problem with this code which comes from your loop counter.  eax starts out as 0, which means it's going to take 5 passes thru the loop (0, 1, 2, 3, 4) for it to equal ebx, which means it's adding some garbage value after the end of `price`.

I've added the `f` suffix after the floats to silence a compiler warning, but that's not really a factor.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    float price[] = { 22.1f, 34.44f, 567.33f, 2.45f };
    float sum = 0;

    __asm {

        xor eax, eax; //counter
        mov ebx, 4 //num elements in array
        lea ecx, price //address of first element in array
        xorps xmm0, xmm0

        L1 :
        addss xmm0, [ecx + eax * 4]
        dec ebx
        jz done

        inc eax
        jmp L1

        done :
        movss sum, xmm0
    }

    cout << "sum= " << sum;

    return 0;
}
```

There's more that could be done to improve this code, but this produces the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

`add` is integer add; you want [`addss xmm0, [ecx+eax*4]`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/addss), and a `movss` store at the end.  Zero xmm0 with `xorps xmm0,xmm0` before the loop, like you were doing with `xor edx,edx` to zero an integer register.

(Look at un-optimized or lightly optimized compiler output from a pure C++ loop for syntax on how to use these if you're not sure.  e.g. in the debugger or on https://godbolt.org/)

---

The integer that results from summing those 4 bit-patterns as integers probably represents (as a binary32 IEEE float) a very small `float` that happens to print a `0.0`

Use the debugger to look at register and variable values while you single step if you want the full details.

Comment: I tried that now, but I am getting some very large number.

Comment: @triassiic: Did you zero xmm0 first?  I was just adding that to my answer when you commented.  Anyway, *use the debugger* (e.g. Visual Studio has a decent one built-in) to look at register values at each step to see where things start going wrong and narrow down where the problem might be.  e.g. if it was uninitialized xmm0, you'd see that by looking at it before the first `addss`.

Comment: I tried to use the debugger, but it only shows eax, ebx, ecx, ... registers. No xmm0 register. I tried zeroing xmm0 with the code xorps xmm0, xmm0 , but the answer is still incorrect.

Comment: If you "right click" inside the registers window, you can add more register types.  Use `SSE` to see xmm0.

Comment: Got it, it shows it as 0, so I'm not really sure what is going wrong.

Comment: A little more info please: It shows 0 before doing the add?  After?  After doing all the adds?  Did you remember to do the movss at the end?

Comment: Before and after all the adds, and I did movss.

Comment: Huh.  Well, if it's 0 after the first add, then there's something wrong with the `addss` instruction.  I can't picture it.  Perhaps if you update your question with the new code?

Comment: @triassiic: you removed the `mov sum, edx`, right?  I meant to *replace* that with `movss sum, xmm0`.  If you left it in, you'd obviously be storing EDX over top of the result.